# Laravel: how to validate relationship when using a route resource identifier that differs from database identifier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I'm working with Laravel nested resources to serve a many-to-many relationship. I'm working on a Football app and I want to link Competitions with Seasons, e.g. Premier League with 2021/22 season.

What I want to achieve is to have a dedicated route to manage this relationship with Seasons being sub-resources of Competitions.

My entities have an auto-generated integer ID at database level, but I'm using `getRouteKeyName()` to define the slug as the field to be used by Laravel for implicit model binding.

Now I'm struggling to make the validation work when posting a new Season under a Competition. The request looks like this:

```
POST /api/competitions/premier-league/seasons/

{
    "season": "21-22",
    ...
}
```

The value "21-22" is the actual slug for the Season object, but I can't manage to use it for validation in the association table, as foreign keys in it use auto-generated ones rather than the column I use for implicit model-binding.

To clarify, the tables look like this:

```
seasons                  competition_editions               competitions
id      slug             id      comp    season             id      slug
X       21-22            Z       Y       X                  Y       premier-league
```

Is there a way to make the unique rule of FormRequest work with model-binding key so that I don't have to manually convert the slug to the actual id of the resource inside the controller?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you validating input into `seasons` or `competition_editions`? If it's the latter then  you can look at [unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) under the part that says *Adding Additional Where Clauses*

Comment: The problem is within the value I'm passing to the API.. I could use unique constraints but these aren't really on the slug, they should be applied to its matching id..

Maybe have a look at the answer I posted just to give a feedback/propose improvements?

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with something but I'm not sure it's the nicest way to handle it.

Basically I used the `prepareForValidation()` on FormRequest to transform the slug into the actual database id of the Season resource.

Here is the code, just to make it clear:

```php
/**
     * Prepare the data for validation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareForValidation() {
        $season = Season::where('slug', $this->season)->first();

        $this->merge([
            'season' => $season != null ? $season->id : 0,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'season' => [
                'required',
                'exists:seasons,id',
                Rule::unique('competition_editions', 'season_id')
                    ->where('competition_id', $this->route('competition')->id),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The thing I like the least is defaulting the id to `0` if the slug doesn't match any Season, but leaving it null would cause a Database Exception within the `exists` rule..